# What is the fundamental difference between pygame.rect.Rect() and pygame.Rect()?

Tags: python, pygame

I tried this and that and was surprised that both methods work and give the same result. But there must be some sense in the difference in spelling, right?

```
rect = pg.rect.Rect(x, y, width, height)
rect = pg.Rect(x, y, width, height)

def draw():
        draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case when you can easily dig into lib internals and investigate it on your own. In fact, there is a line `from pygame.rect import Rect` in `pygame/__init__.py`. There are no other reassignments, so there is no difference. It's just a shortcut for convenience.

Comment: Does this mean I don't have to use **`pg.rect.Rect()`** if I can use **`pg.Rect()`** ?
It's just that in Mettiz's book I saw the syntax exactly **`pg.rect.Rect()`**, and in other examples (video on YouTube and in examples on the site) I saw **`pg.Rect()`**

But you say that there is no fundamental difference and you can use any method of writing?

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll mark your answer as the answer a bit later. I will definitely do it. I just want to wait in case someone else comes in and gives a more detailed explanation. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use any method of writing. Btw, official docs refers to Rect directly: pygame.Rect: https://www.pygame.org/docs/